# How to use CSS inheritance with multiple CSS files?

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side, adminlte

I'm using [AdminLTE](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) as my base for styling. There is a class called `.sidebar-dark-primary`.

In a page I have:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
</aside>
```

Now I have a separate CSS file that is loaded after all other files and only if a condition is met.

I need to change the page to be something like:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-custom elevation-4">
</aside>
```

And `sidebar-custom` comes from the separate file.

How do I inherit `sidebar-custom` from `sidebar-dark-primary` in one file or to `sidebar-light-primary` in another file?

Comment: CSS doesn't have such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. CSS has no feature which lets you write a rule which imports rules from a different ruleset. Nor does it have any feature which changes which classes apply to an element.

In CSS, **inheritance** means "Take the value of a property from the parent element".

In this example one of the links inherits the font colour from the parent div, while the other doesn't (so has the default link colour the browser applies).

```css
#parent {
  color: green;
}

#inherits {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a id="inherits" href="/">
        some text
  </a>
  <br>
  <a id="does-not-inherit" href="/">
        some other text
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could inheritance be achieved using `SASS`?

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS Specificity

Some frontend and CSS frameworks also have a smilar idea. This cannot be solved by simply replacing the class.

You can achieve it by having both classes in the element. This is not really inheritance, but specificity:
[MDN: CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

See snippet below to illustrate this.

```css
/* main file */

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
aside { display: block; color: #999; } /* just for this snippet */
.sidebar { padding: 5px; margin: 10px; border: 2px solid blue; }
.sidebar-dark { background-color: #222; }
.sidebar-dark-primary { background-color: #226; }


/* separate file with customizations */

.sidebar-custom { background-color: #636; border-color: green; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar elevation-4">
Sidebar
</aside>

<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar sidebar-dark elevation-4">
Sidebar: Dark
</aside>

<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
Sidebar: Dark Primary
</aside>

<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar sidebar-dark-primary sidebar-custom elevation-4">
Sidebar: Dark Primary Custom
</aside>

</body>
</html>
```